# Setting unique snapshot version when cross-building in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

When `publish`, if there is `-SNAPSHOT` in a version, I'd like to replace it with a unique timestamp. I've already done this and it works, except for cross-building with `+`.

It seems that the `version` setting I set with the timestamp gets cleared out whenever the Scala version is changed for the cross-build.

When I try to cross-build `publish` I'm using the following command:

```
sbt ";stamp-version ;+publish"
```

Here is the code for the command `stamp-version`:

```
object TimestampVersion {

  import Version.Snapshot

  lazy val versionSettings = Seq(commands += stampVersion)

  def stampVersion = Command.command("stamp-version") { state =>
    val extracted = Project.extract(state)
    extracted.append(List(version in ThisBuild ~= { ver =>
      val stmp = stamp(ver)
      Logging.info("Stamping version %s".format(stmp))
      stmp
    }), state)
  }

  def stamp(version: String): String = {
    if (version endsWith Snapshot) {
      // we use a dot here to not break rpm versioning rules
      (version stripSuffix Snapshot) + "." + timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis)
    } else {
      version
    }
  }

  def timestamp(time: Long): String = {
    // no delimiter between date & time in order to not break rpm versioning rules
    val sdf = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
    sdf.format(new Date(time))
  }
}
```

Is there a different way I can store my timestamped version that can be accessed by my cross-builds?

EDIT: To be clear, I want each cross-built version to have the same timestamp so that when I use it from somewhere else I can depend on like this: `"x" %% "y" % "z"`

Also, it would be best if the solution could work with SBT 0.12.x since I still have that dependency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's recommended approach in SBT `0.13.x`, but the following has seemed to have worked fine for me.

If you need to *"have the same timestamp"* for all versions listed in `crossScalaVersions`, then you may want to leverage [Generating files](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/generatefiles.html), i.e. [IO.write](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/sbt/IO%24.html) and [IO.read](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/api/sbt/IO%24.html) methods, to save a timestamp file with a unique snapshot version.

**NOTE** Do not set `scalaVersion` in `build.sbt` as it overwrites the one set by `+`. That was the problem in my initial answer.

Have the following task `stampVersion` in `build.sbt` (I leave migrating it to SBT < 0.13 as an exercise):

```
lazy val stampVersion = taskKey[File]("Generates timestamp file with unique snapshot version")

stampVersion := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val stmp = System.currentTimeMillis
  val file = target.value / "timestamp"
  log.info(s"Stamping version $stmp saved in $file")
  IO.write(file, s"""$stmp""")
  file
}
```

When you run the task `stampVersion`, a file gets created in `target/timestamp` file.

With the following task, you can read its content.

```
lazy val getStampVersion = taskKey[String]("Retrieves unique snapshot version from timestamp file")

getStampVersion := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  val file = (target in Compile).value / "timestamp"
  val v = IO.read(file)
  log.info(s"Retrieving version from $file: $v [scalaVersion: ${scalaVersion.value}]")
  v
}
```

Use `show getStampVersion` to show the version saved in the file.

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> stampVersion
[info] Stamping version 1390606523705 saved in /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:35:23 AM
[sbt-0-13-1]> show getStampVersion
[info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390606523705 [scalaVersion: 2.10.3]
[info] 1390606523705
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:35:34 AM
```

In order to set `version` key to a timestamped version, I defined a command `setVersionFromStampFile` (as it changes the state of a project).

```
def setVersionFromStampFile = Command.command("setVersionFromStampFile") { state =>
  val e = Project extract state
  import e._
  val (newState, stampVersion) = runTask(getStampVersion, state)
  val scalaV = scalaVersion in currentRef get structure.data getOrElse Nil
  state.log.info(s"scalaVersion: $scalaV")
  val settings = Seq(
    version := stampVersion
  )
  append(settings ++ structure.settings, state)
}

commands += setVersionFromStampFile
```

With the command `setVersionFromStampFile`, whenever it gets run, `version` gets set appropriately.

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> show version
[info] 0.1-SNAPSHOT
[sbt-0-13-1]> setVersionFromStampFile
[info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390606523705 [scalaVersion: 2.10.3]
[info] scalaVersion: 2.10.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[sbt-0-13-1]> show version
[info] 1390606523705
```

In the build definition `build.sbt`, have the setting `crossScalaVersions` defined, e.g.

```
crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.9.3", "2.10.3")
```

Define a command alias `setStampAsVersionAndShow` in `build.sbt` to ease testing - you'll see the values of `version` and `scalaVersion` settings after executing the command `setVersionFromStampFile`:

```
addCommandAlias("setStampAsVersionAndShow",
                "; setVersionFromStampFile ; show version; show scalaVersion")
```

This lets you cross-execute a series of commands:

```
[sbt-0-13-1]> + setStampAsVersionAndShow
[info] Setting version to 2.9.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390606523705 [scalaVersion: 2.9.3]
[info] scalaVersion: 2.9.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[info] 1390606523705
[info] 2.9.3
[info] Setting version to 2.10.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390606523705 [scalaVersion: 2.10.3]
[info] scalaVersion: 2.10.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
[info] 1390606523705
[info] 2.10.3
[info] Setting version to 2.10.3
[info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
```

Define `publishTo` setting and another command alias `setStampAsVersionAndPublish` in `build.sbt`:

```
publishTo := Some(Resolver.file("file", target.value / "xxx"))

addCommandAlias("setStampAsVersionAndPublish",
                "; setVersionFromStampFile ; show scalaVersion ; publish")
```

You should now be able to `publish` as you'd expect:

1. Let's start afresh.

   ```
   [sbt-0-13-1]> clean
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:50:22 AM
   ```
2. Generate a version file.

   ```
   [sbt-0-13-1]> stampVersion
   [info] Stamping version 1390607428495 saved in /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp
   [success] Total time: 0 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:50:28 AM
   ```
3. Check it out with `publish` without cross-building (no `+`).

   ```
   [sbt-0-13-1]> setStampAsVersionAndPublish
   [info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390607428495 [scalaVersion: 2.10.3]
   [info] scalaVersion: 2.10.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   [info] 2.10.3
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-sources.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1...
   [info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.pom
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] :: delivering :: default#sbt-0-13-1_2.10;1390607428495 :: 1390607428495 :: release :: Sat Jan 25 00:50:33 CET 2014
   [info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1390607428495.xml
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/classes...
   [info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/api...
   model contains 2 documentable templates
   [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-javadoc.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.pom
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-sources.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-javadoc.jar
   [success] Total time: 1 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:50:34 AM
   ```
4. Give the final command a go - `+` enters the scene.

   ```
   [sbt-0-13-1]> + setStampAsVersionAndPublish
   [info] Setting version to 2.9.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   [info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390607428495 [scalaVersion: 2.9.3]
   [info] scalaVersion: 2.9.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   [info] 2.9.3
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495-sources.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1...
   [info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495.pom
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] :: delivering :: default#sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3;1390607428495 :: 1390607428495 :: release :: Sat Jan 25 00:50:51 CET 2014
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/classes...
   [info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/ivy-1390607428495.xml
   [info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/api...
   model contains 2 documentable templates
   [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495-javadoc.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.9.3/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495.pom
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495-sources.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3-1390607428495-javadoc.jar
   [success] Total time: 4 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:50:54 AM
   [info] Setting version to 2.10.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   [info] Retrieving version from /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/timestamp: 1390607428495 [scalaVersion: 2.10.3]
   [info] scalaVersion: 2.10.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   [info] 2.10.3
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-sources.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1...
   [info] Wrote /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.pom
   [info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [info] Done updating.
   [info] :: delivering :: default#sbt-0-13-1_2.10;1390607428495 :: 1390607428495 :: release :: Sat Jan 25 00:50:55 CET 2014
   [info]  delivering ivy file to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/ivy-1390607428495.xml
   [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/classes...
   [info] Main Scala API documentation to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/api...
   model contains 2 documentable templates
   [info] Main Scala API documentation successful.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-javadoc.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info] Packaging /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.jar ...
   [info] Done packaging.
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.pom
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-sources.jar
   [info]  published sbt-0-13-1_2.10 to /Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/target/xxx/default/sbt-0-13-1_2.10/1390607428495/sbt-0-13-1_2.10-1390607428495-javadoc.jar
   [success] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 25, 2014 12:50:56 AM
   [info] Setting version to 2.10.3
   [info] Set current project to sbt-0-13-1 (in build file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/)
   ```
5. Display basic information about sbt and the build with `about`.

   ```
   [sbt-0-13-1]> about
   [info] This is sbt 0.13.1
   [info] The current project is {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so/sbt-0.13.1/}sbt-0-13-1 0.1-SNAPSHOT
   [info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.3
   [info] Available Plugins: com.typesafe.sbt.SbtGit, com.typesafe.sbt.SbtProguard, growl.GrowlingTests, np.Plugin, com.timushev.sbt.updates.UpdatesPlugin
   [info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.3
   ```

Comment: Thank Jacek. I updated my question where I should have been more specific. This solution seems like it would have a different timestamp component for each version of Scala being cross-build, which isn't quite as useful for me as it is harder to depend on then.

Comment: @myyk The answer has changed to reflect the requirements. Have as much fun as I did while answering your question (and mastering SBT).

Comment: thanks for everything so far, this is very helpful, and I'll share my 0.12 adaption when I'm done. There is a problem with your solution though, I have the same, it is also in the output above. After setting to version 2.9.3 you can see it is publishing to sbt-0-13-1_2.10 which is wrong, it should be sbt-0-13-1_2.9.3.

Comment: Updated. It seems working fine and `scalaVersion`'s preserved. Give it a go and report back!

Comment: If you do need to set the scalaVersion and have a multi-project build you may have to set scalaVersion in ThisBuild to the version you want. I did it after reading the value when setting the stampVersion and that worked for me.

Comment: @myyk Could you show the code (gist) the would explain *"I did it after reading the value when setting the stampVersion and that worked for me."* I'm not sure I understood.

Comment: Everything else with setting up the alias is basically the same. This how I implemented it. https://gist.github.com/myyk/8642799

Answer (score 1):

We could set the DATETIME in bash like so

```
export DATETIME=`date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`
```

and then build our software like

```
sbt 'set version in ThisBuild := s"1.0.0-${sys.env.get("DATETIME").get}"' +compile +publish
```

This will take care that same timestamp is used for both compile versions.